# What is the best set of javascript tools to develop a multiplatform app, if I want to connect in real-time and offline-first approach?

Tags: javascript, real-time, offline-caching

I've started using Firebase + Ionic + Electron for such a task, but I want to be sure it's the right approach.

Also, I read that you can use CouchDB + PouchDB to solve the offline-first part, but they always name the disadvantage that it does not provide authentication.

The system that I need to develop will be used by the government of my city. First, it will have information on the social development of citizens in need of social assistance. Then, a module will be developed for small health care centers, and more modules are planned in each department.

There are certain public data, which would be shared by the different applications to be developed.

I understand that it is not a trivial task, and that is why I want to hear your opinions.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: As you're asking for opinions, this question should be closed as "primarily opinion based". Stack Overflow questions should be specific and objectively answerable.

Comment: @zzzzBov Oh, I'm sorry about that. It's just my second question here. I need an objectively reliable and fast javascript tool to develop an offline-first and real-time application. Could you help me ask the right question? Reliability and speed of development are more objective measures than simple opinions, right?

Comment: Spend some time reviewing [ask] as well as [what's on topic for Stack Overflow](/help/on-topic). Your comment is leaning toward #4 in the off-topic list. My suggestion is to hop into one of the chat rooms and have a discussion there. Maybe research some case studies with the various technologies you're considering and connect with developer teams that have used those technologies.

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks! I'll do that. Have a nice day!